# How to find and click on specific element using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm starting in the world of python and I'm practicing creating things for my day to day. I decided to automate a routine task, but I can't get selenium to click on a specific place because it changes depending on how many columns I have and those columns always change order when I open a new login.

I thought about trying to find the specific xpath using the place name in the case "CORTEZ" and then find the "" specifies where I can click the button, but this "" is not inside the text "CORTEZ" it is in the same "line" or "group" (I don't know the correct term, forgive me) you will identify this in the image at the end of the text. I have no idea how to do this and I don't even know if it's possible as I said, I'm new to this world and I'm trying to learn little by little. I accept other subjects too

Most complete xpath I've ever tried too:
`// table [@ id = "accordionConvenio_Pane_0_content_GridView1"] / tbody / tr [3] / td / input`

My current code:

```
def confirmarlocal(self):
                try:
                        time.sleep(0.25)
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="accordionConvenio_Pane_0_content_GridView1_ctl05_btnParticipar"]'))).click()
                except TimeoutException:
                        return
```

**NOTE: I CANNOT DOWNLOAD THE HTML CODE THEN FOLLOW A PICTURE BELOW**

[image: CODE HTML]

Answer (score 1):

Find the input based off it's class, title.

```
//input[@class='btnParticipar']
//input[@title='Confirmar']
```

Answer (score -1):

If the problem consists in assembling the correct XPath to the desired tag, you can right-click the tag in the inspection menu, select "Copy" and then copy its XPath to get exactly the value you need, at least on Chrome.

Comment: So I do exactly this way but this xpath is numbered "ct105" and corresponds to this numbering and depending on the position I select another button instead of what I really want. Take a look at the xpath of the code above:

`//*[@id="accordionConvenio_Pane_0_content_GridView1_ctl05_btnParticipar"]`

Comment: There must be something that uniquely identifies the button you're trying to click. Have you tried searching by class "btnParticipar" instead of id?